# OpenCV python - How to constantly update the time output and distance output?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian Wheezy and sporting a USB webcam. My goal is to measure the distance between an object and the camera in realtime.

Following [a guide on how to do so with still images](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/)

This is the code I am currently running :

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2
import datetime
import time

def find_marker(frame):
    # convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and detect edges
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 35, 125)

    # find the contours in the edged image and keep the largest one;
    # we'll assume that this is our piece of paper in the image
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)

    # compute the bounding box of the of the paper region and return it
    return cv2.minAreaRect(c)

def distance_to_camera(knownWidth, focalLength, perWidth):
    # compute and return the distance from the maker to the camera
    return (knownWidth * focalLength) / perWidth

# initialize the known distance from the camera to the object, which
# in this case is 24 inches
KNOWN_DISTANCE = 11.811

# initialize the known object width, which in this case, the piece of
# paper is 11 inches wide
KNOWN_WIDTH = 2.3622

# initialize the list of images that we'll be using
#IMAGE_PATHS = ["images/2ft.png", "images/3ft.png", "images/4ft.png"]

# load the furst image that contains an object that is KNOWN TO BE 2 feet
# from our camera, then find the paper marker in the image, and initialize
# the focal length
#image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATHS[0])
#marker = find_marker(image)
#focalLength = (marker[1][0] * KNOWN_DISTANCE) / KNOWN_WIDTH


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

while(1):

    (grabbed, frame) = cap.read()
    marker = find_marker(frame)
#   for () LOOP THIS TO GET DISTANCE CALCULATION FULLY WORKING!
    focalLength = (marker[1][0] * KNOWN_DISTANCE) / KNOWN_WIDTH
    inches = distance_to_camera(KNOWN_WIDTH, focalLength, marker[1][0])

        # draw a bounding box around the image and display it
        box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(marker))
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        ts = timestamp.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p")
    cv2.putText(frame, "%.2fft" % (inches / 12),
        (frame.shape[1] - 200, frame.shape[0] - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        2.0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.putText(frame, ts, (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)   

    #Write to textfile here and send
#   for () LOOP End

    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# loop over the images
#for imagePath in IMAGE_PATHS:
    # load the image, find the marker in the image, then compute the
    # distance to the marker from the camera
#   image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
#   marker = find_marker(image)
#   inches = distance_to_camera(KNOWN_WIDTH, focalLength, marker[1][0])

    # draw a bounding box around the image and display it
#   box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(marker))
#   cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
#   cv2.putText(image, "%.2fft" % (inches / 12),
#       (image.shape[1] - 200, image.shape[0] - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
#       2.0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
#   cv2.imshow("image", image)
#   cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is my output:

[image]

However, the time (the red text on the bottom left) and the distance detected don't change as the program runs. Is there any way of getting these two values to update until the program ends?

Answer (score 1):

This is why both values are not being updated:

### timestamp

`timestamp` is out of the `while` loop

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
while(1):
```

Should be:

```
while(1):
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
```

---

### distance

`distance_to_camera`, with this parameters, will produce a constant output:

```
# assuming:
# a = KNOWN_WIDTH
# b = focalLength
# c = marker[1][0]
# d = KNOWN_DISTANCE

def distance_to_camera(x,y,z):
    return (x*y)/z

b = c*d/a
inches = distance_to_camera(a,b,c) # => a*b/c
# inches = a*b/c, b = c*d/a
# inches = a*c*d/a*c
# inches = d << constant output
```

that is equal to `KNOWN_DISTANCE`. If you do the math: `KNOWN_DISTANCE / 12 = 0.98425` is the distance you are getting

---

### Edit:

I just read the tutorial, and looks like you should do the `focalLenght` calculation just once, out of the `while`.